# Send push notifications using FCM and React Native (Expo) app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I am building a React Native(Expo) app that can send notifications to another app(not built with react-native). I have the FCM token(device-token) of the target app. How can I send notifications to that app using firebase cloud messaging(FCM)?

The target app is NOT built using react-native and has everything handled for the incoming notification. I just need to send the notification to the target app. Thank you in advance.